# Can someone explain how numpy.cov works?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 32x96 array array=[32x96].

When I perform the `np.cov(array)` it returns a 32x32 array or if I transpose the array it returns a 96x96 array. I am trying to find the covariance between each of the 96 positions, across all 32 trials. I just don't understand why the array is 2 dimensional, I thought it would return a 1-D array thats either 32 or 96.

Answer (score 0):

let's make an example we can visualize:

```
X = np.random.randn(6).reshape(3,2)
#Output
[[ 0.26076539, -0.04107355],
 [ 0.86502104,  0.67499596],
 [ 0.3184734 , -1.57163825]]

C = np.cov(X)
#Output
[[0.04555337, 0.02867848, 0.28525465],
 [0.02867848, 0.01805476, 0.17958431],
 [0.28525465, 0.17958431, 1.78626103]]
```

As you can see the matrix is symmetric. Along the dianagonal there is the variance of each input column and the other elements are the covariance according to the logic:

```
C_{ij} = cov(x_i,x_j)
```

So I belive what you want is the first row (or first column, of course).
Sorry, I don't know how to write formulas here